# Navigation drawer in all activities

Tags: android, xml, navigation

i am using navigation view for navigation drawer...and there are certain menu items int he drawer and when i clicked on a particular a new activity opens and i want to open navigation drawer from that activity too.. i tried one way in which i had to extends my main activity(the one having drawer) to the activity (or the second activity)...and add this in my second activity instead of setcontentview.. but the thing is my second activity xml is just above the mainactivity.xml.. i see both the activity one above the other(secondactivity above mainactivity.xml) how to just show only secondactivity with the drawer.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View activityView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_credits, null,false);
        // add the custom layout of this activity to frame layout.
        drawerLayout.addView(activityView);
```

Comment: When you click on a drawer in your main activity, does it open a new activity or just shows a fragment?

Comment: opens a new activity(say secondactivity)

Comment: Have you tried setting the content view instead of inflating it? When you start a new activity, you can't inflate it, you should use setcontentview. Edit: why don't you use fragments? It keeps the same navigation drawer throughout the navigation

Comment: i tried setting contentview but drawer is not opening.. actually i have searched a lot and the solution is have to inflate it... and i just didn't use fragments and now i m in middle of my project..i cant switch to fragments now..i just forgot to use fragments...so any help in this???

Comment: So this is the old way but with a little tuning, you'll get there: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html It's done with one main activity which has a drawer and calls several fragments

Comment: so i had to convert all my activities into fragments

Comment: Yes, basically that's the idea. Define layouts for your fragments and then inflate them according to the selected drawer

Comment: aaaaagggghhhhh!!!!! thanks by the way.....

Comment: No problem, the idea of navigation drawer is to show fragments, not activities, so I hope the link helps you

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this task by creating one common class say BaseActivity.java and put your code of navigation drawer in this class. and extend your classes with BaseActivity.java where you want to show navigation drawer.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    public Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object


    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    Context context;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected boolean useToolbar() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        context = this;

        DrawerLayout fullView = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_main, null);
        FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) fullView.findViewById(R.id.frame);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);

        super.setContentView(fullView);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) fullView.findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        this.getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_arrahm);
        //  toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_main);
        if (useToolbar()) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            setTitle("Places Near Me");
        } else {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        //Initializing NavigationView
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.edit_profile:                   
                        return true;
                    case R.id.change_password:
                        return true;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Work in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView tvEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.email);
        String name = Preferences.getDataFromStringPreferences(context,Constants.USER_DETAILS, Constants.USER_NAME);

        if (name != null) {
            tvName.setText(name);
        }


        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

create drawer_main.xml layout file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer">


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

create toolbar.xml under layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

create drawer_header.xml layout resource file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="178dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text=""

            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```